# ESB to SAP connection working but getting an BAD request 400 error but with Soap UI am not getting it

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio, mule-component, http-status-code-400

**Configuration XML**

```html
<sap:connectorname="SAP" jcoAsHost="1.1.1.1" jcoUser="test_User" jcoPasswd="password" jcoSysnr="00" jcoClient="20" jcoLang="EN" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SAP" />
<flow name="testFlow2" doc:name="testFlow2" />
<flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
  <composite-source doc:name="Composite Source">
    <sap:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="SAP" type="function" xmlVersion="2" outputXml="true" jcoGwHost="1.1.1.1" jcoGwService="3300" jcoProgramId="muletest" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SAP" />
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="test" doc:name="HTTP" />
  </composite-source>
  <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
  <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://www.test.com" doc:name="HTTP" />
  <set-variable variableName="code" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status']]" doc:name="Variable" />
  <set-payload value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;Z_SD_CALL_TO_SVS&gt;&lt;export&gt;&lt;RESPONSE&gt;&lt;code&gt;#[flowVars.code]&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/RESPONSE&gt;&lt;/export&gt;&lt;/Z_SD_CALL_TO_SVS&gt;" doc:name="Set Payload"
  />
</flow>
</mule>
```

The above is the configuration file.
When i send data from Soap UI am getting response code as 400 and sending it back to SOAP UI and I dint face any problem but when i send the data via SAP connector the data is sent to SAP but in console am getting error like below.

```html
Message : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://www.test.com, connector=HttpsConnector { name=HTTP_HTTPS lifecycle=start this=29a1ffa numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4 createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
connected=true supportedProtocols=[https] serviceOverrides=
<none>
  } , name='http://www.test.com', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={http.method=POST, exceptionOnMessageError=true, Content-Type=application/xml}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false,
  initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod Code : MULE_ERROR-42999 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Exception stack is: 1. Bad Request, code: 400 (org.mule.transport.http.HttpResponseException) org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher:285 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/http/HttpResponseException.html)
  2. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://www.test.com/, connector=HttpsConnector { name=HTTP_HTTPS lifecycle=start this=29a1ffa numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4 createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[https] serviceOverrides=
  <none>
    } , name='endpoint.https.svc.cert.storedvalue.com.ecomm.0.1.fulfillment.0.1.purchasephysical', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={http.method=POST, exceptionOnMessageError=true, Content-Type=application/xml}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null,
    action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
    org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher:285 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html) -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Root Exception
    stack trace: org.mule.transport.http.HttpResponseException: Bad Request, code: 400 at org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher.doSend(HttpClientMessageDispatcher.java:285) at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher.process(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:84)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$DispatcherMessageProcessor.process(AbstractConnector.java:2637) + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything) Y am not getting error when trying with SoapUI and
```